# Program.exe has stopped working when trying to open file

Tags: c, file, input

```
void formFile(FILE** f, char** name)
{
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    if (1 == doesFileExist(*name, f))
    {
        printf("Already exists.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Here's `doesFileExist(char*, FILE**)`:

```
int doesFileExist(char *name, FILE ** f)
{
    if(NULL == (*f = fopen(name, "wb")))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;

}
```

In `formFile()`, when I comment out the `if`, the code runs without any errors. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No one has any idea. Please post a [mcve]. Besides, your function named doesFileExist creates a file if it does not exist, is this what you want?

Comment: Time to enable all warnings and debug info when compiling (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and to learn how to use the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `doesFileExist()` you return 1 if `fopen()` succeeds and 0 if it fails. But in `formFile()` you print an error message if `doesFileExist()` returns 1, in other words, if everything is OK.

Another problem is. that you call `scanf( "%s", name );` with `char **name` but `%s` expects a `char *` as argument (pointing to a sufficient array) so you should do something like

```
int size = /* large enough */;
*name = malloc( size );
scanf( "%s", *name );
```

or better use `fgets( *name, size, stdin );` instead of `scanf()` as it automatically reads at most `size-1` characters.

Answer (score 0):

it should be either W+ or W

correct:

```
 *f = fopen(name, "r"); 
      if(f){
        return 1;//fike exist
       }
   return 0;
```

Comment: @grizloni97  try the above code.                                                                             P.S in C never practiced with binary that why the mistake

Comment: Wrong, "b" is a valid optional mode flag for fopen. Read the documentation carefully.